# Compress old log file into single zip-linux

Tags: shell, find, tar, gzip

I have a folder `/home/testuser/log` which contain log files of one day old `*.log`. I wish to compress all the log files older than one day to a single zip(gzip or tar.gz) and delete the older files.

I tried to pipeline find and tar commands but didn't work

Comment: If you need to do this more than once, [`logrotate`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) is your friend

Comment: @sr_ Maybe you can extend it in an answer?

Comment: I am planning to put a job in cron tab to do this.
I compress-->Move to another location. This is what I am planning to do.. but not able to compress all files into one zip/gz

Comment: what do you mean by " delete the older files." , you want compress then delete those same files which are compressed ?

Comment: sorry for the confusion giving an example
example:
log1 created  today log2 log3 are old. Compress log2 log3-->output.gz then delete log2 and log3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create tar.gz files older than one day logs

```
find /home/testuser/log/ -mtime +1 | xargs  tar -czvPf  /opt/older_log_$(date +%F).tar.gz
```

Delete older files [ Note:- if below find output is Correct then remove echo , after that it will delete those files]

```
find /home/testuser/ -mtime +1 | xargs  -n1 echo rm
```

Comment: For the second part, you can simply type: **find /home/testuser/ -mtime +1 -delete**

Answer (score 1):

Extending sr_'s comment, I'm using logrotate to housekeep a nightly SQL dump. I have this configuration in `/etc/logrotate.d/mydbdump`:

```
/var/backups/dump.sql {
        daily
        rotate 7
        missingok
        create 640 root root
        compress
}
```

It basically takes the `/var/backups/dump.sql` file (you would specify the name of your logfile instead), compresses it and renames it to `dump.sql.1.gz`. Before that, it rotates the old `dump.sql.1.gz` to `dump.sql.2.gz` and so on, and deletes the oldest one.

`logrotate` itself is usually called by `cron`, so have a look at your `/etc/cron*` directories to control when it's run.

Comment: Great suggestion, yet it doesn't meet the "to a single zip" requirement of the OP yet.

Comment: I have few log files log1.log log2.log
my idea was to take created date of files 

`if(created date=current date-1)
compress all, move to new location, Delete older files`

Comment: @b00tbu9 `logrotate` does this for you. If you look at your `/var/log` dir and notice the `*.#.gz` files you'll see its results.

Comment: @gertvdijk if the single zip file is a requirement, I'd suggest using the `prerotate`/`postrotate` options to manually merge the input/output files.